# Error displaying Swagger UI of flask-restx in Deployment using uwsgi and nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, swagger, uwsgi, flask-restx

I have implemented a flask rest server with swagger-ui using flask-restx.
I could get the swagger-ui working when running the server using command, without nginx

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

or

```
uwsgi --ini app.ini
```

My `app.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 2

socket = /tmp/myproj.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

====================

However, with nginx, although my REST APIs are working, I couldn't get the swagger-UI.
Error message I received on browser:

[image]

My nginx configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    server_name _;

    location /api {     
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/myproj.sock;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to configure nginx so that swagger-UI could be loaded?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I got exactly the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Phipsen, I have posted my solution below. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update

I managed to make it works by adding /swaggerui in nginx configuration.

Example code:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  
  location /api {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/myproj.sock;
  }

  location /swaggerui {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/myproj.sock;
  }

}
```